# How can I edit a PDF in ubuntu to change its opening settings?

Tags: pdf, ubuntu-gnome

On Windows I used Acrobat pro to edit a PDF so that it opened scaled to fit the window not just at some random scale (like 137%).

I'm not interested in changing it in my PDF viewer, there are settings in a PDF that control this and I want to change those so that those who I send it to see the full page and not just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you create these pdfs with Libreoffice, you can set such preferences during pdf export (Export as pdf --> Initial view --> Magnification.

Depending on the complexity of the pdf you can also open a pdf in Libreoffice Draw and reexport it with the desired setting.

Otherwise you can use pdfXchange viewer via wine (it is commercial, but significantly cheaper than adobe pro and works flawlessly under wine), or you can give pdfedit (native) a try.

To install pdfedit: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538966/how-can-i-install-pdfedit-on-ubuntu-14-04)

To change initial view with pdfedit (from [here](http://www.lancejian.com/2012/03/10/change-pdf-file-initial-view.html) )

```
Open the PDF file in pdfedit, right click the "catalog" node in the tree panel, choose "add item to dictionary"
Add property name: "PageLayout"
Select "name" and input "TwoPageRight"
Click "add and close"
Save the PDF file
```

This adds a name in the catalog dictionary of PDF file. It will be used by the Acrobat Reader. There are other possibilities:

```
SinglePage
OneColumn
TwoColumnLeft
TwoColumnRight
TwoPageLeft
TwoPageRight
```

"Column" means continuous page. "Page" means display as a single page. "Left" means start double pages with odd-numbered pages on the left.

Comment: I'll have a look at this... thanks. I was hoping for some linux way of doing this... that didn't cost anything.

Comment: It might be quite important to know how you create these pdfs.

Comment: I use inkscape, but I couldn't see any settings about the initial zoom

Comment: Then LO Draw might not be the right tool, above I included instructions for pdfedit. I did not test them.